# JSON Api Relationships and DDD Principles

Tags: rest, domain-driven-design, api-design

In my current project we try to use DDD as development process and foundation of our architecture. For the REST-Interfaces it has been decided, that [JSON:API](https://jsonapi.org/) is our way to go.

Since DDD, REST and JSON:API are all rather new concepts for us, I might have some major missconceptions about them.

In the example from jsonapi.org, we have two (or more) main ressource types: *articles* and *people*

With the relationship, that articles are authored by people. In DDD I would say, I have two aggregate roots, where the article references the author by it's ID.
According to my expectations, JSON:API provides the two endpoints:

- `/articles/{articleId}`
- `/people/{peopleId}`

Also to my expectations, in the JSON:API-Structure for an article, if find a *relationship* named *author* to a *people*. But there is also the thing that irritates me:

```
      "author": {
        "links": {
          "self": "http://example.com/articles/1/relationships/author",
          "related": "http://example.com/articles/1/author"
        },
        "data": { "type": "people", "id": "9" }
      },
```

I am aware that the URIs here are not mandatory, and the data would be sufficient. Now I wonder, would it be right to have the URIs there, in this manner in the context of DDD? Accroding to the Specification

> *A “related resource link” provides access to resource objects linked in a relationship.*

I interprete that in a way, that with the URI *[http://example.com/articles/1/author"](http://example.com/articles/1/author%22)* I indeed access the aggregate root *people with id 9*. This interpretation is supported, as the response claims to be in a relationship to it`"self": "http://example.com/people/9`.

So, with this, I retrive, to possible interact, an aggregate root through another aggregate root, instead of using it's own repository. To me, this feels wrong.

Under the guidelines of DDD, should I allow the URI `http://example.com/articles/1/author` or not? Why does JSON:API not return

```
      "author": {
        "links": {
          "self": "http://example.com/articles/1/relationships/author",
          "related": "http://example.com/people/9"
        },
        "data": { "type": "people", "id": "9" }
      },
```

or would that be an appropriate response, also?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that DDD doesn't have anything to say about how you structure your JSON endpoints. Can you provide any evidence that states otherwise?

Comment: Have a look [here](https://mattallan.me/posts/rest-and-ddd/#mapping-rest-resources-on-to-domain-entities:~:text=There%20isn%E2%80%99t%20really%20any%20point%20to,resources%20to%20domain%20actions%2C%20not%20entities.)

Comment: @RobertHarvey Thanks for the article. It's intersting. I am unsure whether I have read it, or it was my own intuition, but to me it seemed obvious that the API should be just as much domain driven - maybe from the viewpoint of the client's domain - as the core itself.  
Further, having the URI `http://example.com/articles/1/author` tells the wrong story, suggesting the author is indeed part of an article.